# Pixelated Logo in Office Store

Tags: office-store

our Office Add-in shows a pixelated icon in the list of Add-ins.

[image: Pixelated logo]

We're using following declerations in our manifest file:

```
<IconUrl DefaultValue="logo-32x32.png" />
<HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="logo-64x64.png"/>
```

According to the documentation of [HighResolutionIconUrl element](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/highresolutioniconurl)
 and [IconUrl element](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/iconurl)
 these are the only attributes to set.

Is there a way to ensure the App Icon is displayed correctly?

Comment: Hi Alx, This is displaying as expected.  I've relayed your feedback on the quality of the display to the engineering team responsible for the App Icon display. Thanks for letting us know.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Please let me know if we can change or adjust anything on our side to improve it.